# How to display a radio button selected using a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a variable that contains a radio button value. I check some  conditions, and based on this value the radio button will be selected.

```
if(cheque_date == system_date) {
   cheque_value='Current';
}
else {
   cheque_value='PDC';  
}  
cheque_value = $('input[name=cheque_type]:checked').val();
```

Radio button:

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="cheque_type" value="Current" />Current
</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="cheque_type" value="PDC" />PDC
</label>
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check radio button based on value like following.

```
 if(cheque_date == system_date) {
     cheque_value='Current';
 }
 else {
     cheque_value='PDC';  
 }  
 $('input[name=cheque_type][value="'+cheque_value+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code below ?

```
if(cheque_date == system_date)
    cheque_value = 'Current';
} else {
    cheque_value = 'PDC';
}
$("input[name='cheque_type'][value='"+cheque_value+"']").prop("checked",true);
var inputValue = $("input[name='cheque_type']:checked").val();
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: triggering not solves the value issue and I improved my answer and you can see demo of solution on link [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aj1ffsy6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need some modifications in your code:

1) Add ids to your checkboxes. In HTML, id attribute is unique, so selecting elements with id is much more faster than by classes or tags.

2) Get id in a variable and use that runtime variable in jQuery.

Final code:

```
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="cheque_type" value="Current" value="Current"/>Current</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="cheque_type" value="PDC" value="PDC" />PDC</label>
```

AND jQuery code:

```
var cheque_id = (cheque_date == system_date) ? 'Current' : 'PDC';
cheque_value = $('#'+cheque_type+':checked').val();
```